# Unity Microphone not working, error stopping the game

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, microphone

I am trying to make a real-time voice chat, or something close to real-time. I've used the microphone. start however I do not understand if I should be hearing my voice. That aside the issue is the error I am getting... 
I've identified the microphone used on the pc and have set it to within the code.

I am using the network class, making a multiplayer game.

error: 'ArgumentException: Exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' was thrown. Mic.Start () (at Assets/Script/Mic.cs:27)'

[CODEC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vmtf.png) [Input & Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaUBJ.png)

```
[SyncVar] int seconds = 10;
[SyncVar] int frequency = 44100;


void Start(){

    if (!isLocalPlayer){
        return;
    }

    audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    audioSource.clip = Microphone.Start("Realtek High Definition Audio", true, seconds, frequency);
    while (!(Microphone.GetPosition("Realtek High Definition Audio") > 0)) {
    }
    audioSource.Play();
    Debug.Log("---------------- audio source ---------------- " + audioSource.clip);
}


void Update()
{
    foreach (string device in Microphone.devices)
    {
        Debug.Log("name" + device);
        deviceMic = device;
    }

}

//void recordAudio() {
//    float[] data = new float[frequency];
//    int micPosition = Microphone.GetPosition(null) - (frequency + 1);
//    audioSource.clip.GetData(data, micPosition);
//}
```

}

Comment: Which is line 27 of Mic.cs?

Comment: @jdweng audioSource.clip = Microphone.Start() <- this one

Comment: You have different CODEC on machine.  You are asking for following : "Realtek High Definition Audio".  Look at PC Device Manager and check which CODEC is installed.

Comment: @jdweng I've attached the CODEC (two links to the images taken of the device manager. As you can see I do have 'Reaktek High Definition Audio'.

Comment: I think something is wrong with the settings/parameters.  Maybe the Frequency should be in KHz?  See : https://www.gigabyte.com/fileupload/tw/microsite/117/hd_audio_driver_usermanualver1-00_0418-05.pdf (page 15)